# How to use null/ not-null as a boolean using a hibernate type in GORM

Tags: hibernate, grails-orm

I have a GORM project and we have a concept of seasonality. Therefore if we see an entry without a year we know the object is seasonal. This means I want to create a column mapping (or some such thing if I am off base) that sets a Boolean to true if the column is blank (null and false if it is not. This property will not be persisted.

What is the best way to handle this sort of thing? Do I have to go through all the overhead of a custom UserType?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using UserType you can use Hibernate calculated property instead. Please see documentation for [details](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2009).

```
@Formula("(select
           case 
           when some_field is null or some_field = '' then 'Y'
           else 'N'
           end
           from some_table")
private boolean isEmpty;
```

Comment: Yes of course. Just a little bit diffrent approach/syntax. Please see details [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.8/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties).